# Why does larger texture render faster in webgl?

Tags: three.js

Run the following jsfiddle code with size = 256, we got ~60ms/frame performance. While setting size = 1024, we got ~10ms/frame. Does anyone know why is a larger sized texture renders faster in this case?
Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/weilun/bfchn7yv/11/, check console log for printed timing info.

```
  var width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;
  var size = 1024; // use these we got 60ms / frame, while use 1024 we got 10ms / frame
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, texture, mesh;

  function changeCanvas() {
      ctx.font = '20pt Arial';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.fillRect(10, 10, canvas.width - 20, canvas.height - 20);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.fillText(new Date().getTime(), canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  }

  function init() {
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(width, height);

      scene = new THREE.Scene();

      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, width / height, 1, 1000);
      camera.position.z = 500;
      scene.add(camera);

      texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
      var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
      geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      scene.add( mesh );

      canvas.width = canvas.height = size;

      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  }

  function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      var s = performance.now()

      mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
      for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
          changeCanvas();
          texture.needsUpdate = true;
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }

      console.log('total: ', performance.now() - s)

  }

  init();
  animate();
```

I'm trying to do some optimizations on another project by switching to smaller textures, but it actually made it worse :-(

Comment: It might help if you give us a working example we can look at.

Comment: I think the code I pasted can be saved as an html and run in browsers, no?

Comment: If you want help, you have to make it easy for people to help you. The editor on stackoverflow has code input (like jsfiddle etc), try using it.

Comment: That's a good suggestion :-) Included!

Comment: So your generating a new canvas texture every frame? I would not expect that to perform well. In any case, why do you have that for loop in the animate function? It seems to be there for no reason at all, take it out and you will see a massive improvement.

Comment: The canvas is only generated once on top. And it is only updated in the animation loop through drawing, no? Can you point me to which lines you think generates the canvas in the animation look in jsfiddle?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame(animate)` makes the animate function run every frame, inside it you have `for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {`. Remore that loop, It is not doing anything that I can see, other than drastically slowing things down (changing the canvas and rendering 100 times per frame :/ )

Comment: I added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the for loop in the animate function.
I can see no use for it and it is generating, applying the texture and rendering the scene 100 times per frame.

```
function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      var s = performance.now()

      mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
      for (var i=0; i<100; i++) { <----remove this line
          changeCanvas();
          texture.needsUpdate = true;
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }                          <-----and this line
      console.log('total: ', performance.now() - s)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It indeed has no effect for rendering the scene. The point of the for loop is only to measure the time more accurately. So by ~10ms/frame I actually meant  ~10ms/100frames. If we remove for loop, the measurement will be inaccurate. I actually just got good performance boost by switching to a 400x400 texture. It seems 256 is a magic number smh, but at least it works for now :-)

Comment: ahh I see, The main problem is that you are changing the texture every frame. You probably also want to stick the the "power of 2" rule for the texture size (256, 512, 1024 etc.). The next step to optimizing might be to implement a custom shader rather than drawing a canvas texture every frame.